# Can xmlNodeGetContent() return NULL?

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

libxml2 has function `xmlNodeGetContent()`, which is documented as follows in http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeGetContent:

```
xmlChar *xmlNodeGetContent  (const xmlNode * cur)
```

> Read the value of a node, this can be either the text carried directly by this node if it's a TEXT node or the aggregate string of the values carried by this node child's (TEXT and ENTITY_REF). Entity references are substituted.
>
> cur:  the node being read
>   Returns:    a new #xmlChar * or NULL if no content is available. It's up to the caller to free the memory with xmlFree().

If `cur` is an empty node, for example `<foo/>` (or the equivalent `<foo></foo>`), then `xmlNodeGetContent()` returns an empty string, not `NULL`, and that is fine IMO.

But then, in which case would `xmlNodeGetContent()` return `NULL`? What would be a minimalistic XML example where that would happen?

Answer (score 3):

If the node passed to xmlNodeGetContent is NULL the return value will be NULL:

```
xmlNode *current_node = NULL;
xmlChar *ret_val;

ret_val = xmlNodeGetContent(current_node);

if(ret_val == NULL)
    printf("ret_val is NULL\n");
```

If the node is a Valid xmlNode, the function could return NULL in different cases, you can check the function in tree.c:

```
xmlChar *xmlNodeGetContent(const xmlNode *cur)
{
if(cur == NULL)
    return (NULL);
switch(cur->type)
    {
    case XML_DOCUMENT_FRAG_NODE:
    case XML_ELEMENT_NODE:
        {
        xmlBufPtr buf;
        xmlChar *ret;

        buf = xmlBufCreateSize(64);
        if(buf == NULL)
            return (NULL);
        xmlBufGetNodeContent(buf, cur);
        ret = xmlBufDetach(buf);
        xmlBufFree(buf);
        return (ret);
        }
    case XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE:
        return (xmlGetPropNodeValueInternal((xmlAttrPtr)cur));
    case XML_COMMENT_NODE:
    case XML_PI_NODE:
        if(cur->content != NULL)
            return (xmlStrdup(cur->content));
        return (NULL);
    case XML_ENTITY_REF_NODE:
        {
        xmlEntityPtr ent;
        xmlBufPtr buf;
        xmlChar *ret;

        /* lookup entity declaration */
        ent = xmlGetDocEntity(cur->doc, cur->name);
        if(ent == NULL)
            return (NULL);

        buf = xmlBufCreate();
        if(buf == NULL)
            return (NULL);

        xmlBufGetNodeContent(buf, cur);

        ret = xmlBufDetach(buf);
        xmlBufFree(buf);
        return (ret);
        }
    case XML_ENTITY_NODE:
    case XML_DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
    case XML_NOTATION_NODE:
    case XML_DTD_NODE:
    case XML_XINCLUDE_START:
    case XML_XINCLUDE_END:
        return (NULL);
    case XML_DOCUMENT_NODE:
    #ifdef LIBXML_DOCB_ENABLED
    case XML_DOCB_DOCUMENT_NODE:
    #endif
    case XML_HTML_DOCUMENT_NODE:
        {
        xmlBufPtr buf;
        xmlChar *ret;

        buf = xmlBufCreate();
        if(buf == NULL)
            return (NULL);

        xmlBufGetNodeContent(buf, (xmlNodePtr)cur);

        ret = xmlBufDetach(buf);
        xmlBufFree(buf);
        return (ret);
        }
    case XML_NAMESPACE_DECL:
        {
        xmlChar *tmp;

        tmp = xmlStrdup(((xmlNsPtr)cur)->href);
        return (tmp);
        }
    case XML_ELEMENT_DECL:
        /* TODO !!! */
        return (NULL);
    case XML_ATTRIBUTE_DECL:
        /* TODO !!! */
        return (NULL);
    case XML_ENTITY_DECL:
        /* TODO !!! */
        return (NULL);
    case XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
    case XML_TEXT_NODE:
        if(cur->content != NULL)
            return (xmlStrdup(cur->content));
        return (NULL);
    }
return (NULL);
}
```

Comment: True. What I am looking for, however, is a **valid** XML node for which `xmlNodeGetContent()` would return `NULL`. Does such a scenario exist?

Comment: Thanks, but I am still unable to get a node for which `xmlNodeGetContent()` returns `NULL`. For example, in the XML document `<?xml version="1.0"?><xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><xs:notation/></xs:schema>`, `xmlNodeGetContent()` returns non `NULL` for node `<xs:notation/>`, even though the source code of `xmlNodeGetContent()` says that `NULL` is returned for `XML_NOTATION_NODE`. I suppose I am missing something obvious?

Comment: An XML schema **is** XML. I tried with `<xs:notation/>` because the source code you posted mentioned `XML_NOTATION_NODE` as causing `xmlNodeGetContent()`to return `NULL`.

If you can suggest any concrete XML example (schema or not), please let me know.